# Using fresh i3 with regolith desktop together

Tags: 18.04, i3-wm

I'm using ubuntu 18.04.5 with regolith desktop. Can I use fresh i3 like this
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxDPh.png)

With regolith desktop together?

Comment: I would try making a backup, then install i3 independently. It looks like regolith i3 gets its settings from /etc/regolith/i3, whereas there is still a /etc/i3 folder, which seems to have no effect in regular use.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz thanks

Comment: Please provide the result. Did it work?